# ¿Puede decirse “arribar en”?

Tags: verbos, preposiciones

Acabo de leer en un titular que un par de políticos “arribaron en” un lugar e inmediatamente me dio la sensación de que está mal, ya que debería ser “arribaron a”. Por analogía con *llegar*, al menos.

[image]

A mí me suena a anglicismo (de *arrive in* o *arrive at*), pero a decir verdad no pude encontrar en el DLE ni en el DPD ninguna indicación expresa de que la preposición deba ser *a* y no pueda ser *en*.

¿Es correcto decir *arribar en un lugar*?

Comentario *a posteriori*: la mayoría de las lenguas europeas romances, y de las germánicas al menos el inglés y el alemán, usan los verbos de movimiento del tipo "ir" y "llegar" con preposiciones locativas (como *en*) en vez de direccionales (como *a*). El castellano parece una excepción en su preferencia por *a*.

Comment: Dudo que sea anglicismo, en inglés se usa *at* mucho más que *in* con el verbo *arrive*

Comment: Sí, corrijo: *arrive* se usa con preposiciones locativas como *in* o bien *at*.

Answer (score 2):

Aunque *arribar* se suele usar con la preposición *a*, también es totalmente válido su sin indicación locativa.  Es decir, podemos sencillamente decir

> El Senador Pichetto y el Ministro Frigerio arribaron.

Y es una frase bien hecha.  Hay ejemplos de usar tanto *a* con *en* para distintos lugares.  Por ejemplo tenemos:

> Pero todas estas conclusiones a las que se arriban en estos congresos de aseguradoras nunca quedan encorsetadas dentro de los mismos.

Aquí, arribamos *a* una conclusión, pero *en* los congresos.  Es decir, *a* representa el lugar conclusivo y *en* un lugar que engloba lo demás.  En este sentido, cuando leo *arribaron en* en tu noticia, lo convierto así:

> El Senador Pichetto y el Ministro Frigerio arribaron (Lugar de acaecemiento: la Rioja)

Si fuese *a*, en vez de *lugar de acaecimiento*, lo habría puesto como *destino: la Rioja*.  En una noticia, no me parece muy extraño porque estamos acostumbrados a titulares de tipo «En X lugar, Y hecho».  De hecho, que tiene *pasadas las 10*, suena muy a que estuviesen diciendo «oye, estamos aquí en directo en La Rioja, y ahora pasadas las 10, han llegado/arribado por fin»

Comment: Los ejemplos de "en" que das no demuestran que "arribar" pueda regir la preposición "en": arribar a conclusiones en un congreso (rige "a"), estamos en la Rioja, y han arribado (es "estar" el verbo que rige "en")

Comment: @gustavson no era no intención decir que *en* sea preposición de régimen, solo que es posible emplear *también* un complemento locativo típico, y entonces debe ser posible también el uso de dicho complemento cuando se usa el verbo a secas (sin su complemento de régimen)

Comment: Creo que *arribar* con *en* siempre lleva además un argumento con *a*. O sea: en algo como *Arribamos a una conclusión en el congreso*, se puede suprimir *en el congreso* pero no *a una conclusión*.

Comment: @pablodf76 Tal vez pero encuentro muchos ejemplares de *arribar en el puerto X*, sin el complemento con *a* Por ejemplo https://books.google.com/books?id=GZVbAAAAcAAJ&pg=RA4-PT66&dq=%22arribaron+en+el%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjCurGLkorjAhVhg-AKHc-sC_cQ6AEISjAE#v=onepage&q=%22arribaron%20en%20el%22&f=false o también en *Las sergas de Esplandián* (varias veces, pero por ejemplo: *arribaron en el puerto de Vuisant*)

Comment: Aquí un uso de *en [lugar] … a [propósito]*: https://books.google.com/books?id=Hc7CrK_65qQC&pg=PA310&dq=%22arribo+en+el%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjpg56hmorjAhWNiOAKHZs9DbkQ6AEIbzAJ#v=onepage&q=%22arribo%20en%20el%22&f=false

Comment: En forma sustantival: https://books.google.com/books?id=skVAAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA22&dq=%22arribo+en+el%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjbupDXmorjAhWym-AKHaHvCZ84ChDoAQg8MAI#v=onepage&q=%22arribo%20en%20el%22&f=false (intento limitarme a textos que serán más castizos)

Answer (score 2):

Me centro en los dos primeros significados de **arribar**:

> [**arribar**](https://dle.rae.es/?id=3kLYZsC)
>   `Del lat.`*`*arripāre`*`, der. de`*`ripa`*`'orilla'.`
>
> 1. intr. Dicho de una nave: Llegar a un puerto.
> 2. intr. Llegar por tierra a cualquier parte. U. t. c. prnl.

El uso de *"arribar en"* puede ser válido según la definición que se esté usando.

Así, por la primera definición, se puede entender "arribar" como "llegar a puerto". Ya incluye un locativo: *a puerto*, lo cual hoy en día incluiría también a los aeropuertos y por tanto sería incluso equivalente a "tomar tierra":

> El senador y el ministro *arribaron* **en** La Rioja → El senador y el ministro *llegaron a puerto* **en** La Rioja → El ministro y el senador *tomaron tierra* **en** La Rioja.

Esto es válido porque la primera definición ya "gasta" el uso del locativo para indicar que se llega "a puerto", por tanto para indicar el sitio en el que está dicho puerto se usa "en".

Por otra parte, si usamos la segunda definición, esta no incluye un locativo específico, se define como "llegar por tierra" (a cualquier parte), y entonces lo correcto sería usar "a" para introducir el locativo:

> El senador y el ministro *arribaron* **a** La Rioja. → El senador y el ministro llegaron por tierra **a** La Rioja. → El senador y el ministro llegaron **a** La Rioja.

El uso pronominal que acepta la segunda definición, es decir el uso de **arribarse**, no altera lo anterior:

> El senador y el ministro *se arribaron* **a** La Rioja. → El senador y el ministro se llegaron por tierra **a** La Rioja. → El senador y el ministro se llegaron **a** La Rioja.

Al final la elección de una preposición u otra depende de si llegaron por tierra, o lo hicieron por mar o aire:

- **arribar** con el sentido de **llegar por barco o por avión**: *arribar **en***
- **arribar** con el sentido de **llegar por tierra**: *arribar **a***

Answer (score 1):

Puede decirse, pero no en este caso. Efectivamente arribar es sinónimo de llegar. Se llega y se arriba a un lugar y puede ser el caso de arribar en algún medio de transporte. El caso de esa noticia es incorrecta, pero el de esta no lo es.

[image]

Comment: el terror de la ambigüedad, muy buen ejemplo.

Answer (score 1):

Buscando en la *Nueva Gramática*, hay solo seis citas que incluyen el verbo *arribar*:

> - Y de toda España arribó una caterva de aventureros, ganapanes, gentilhombres, ladrones, santos, asesinos. (cit. en §3.5c, pág. 152)
> - El gremio del taxismo informal arriba a la Presidencia a entregar propuestas para el Reglamento. (cit. en §6.4p, pág. 444)
> - Andaba por la hache y me parecía imposible arribar a la zeta (cit. en 14.2j, pág 1034)
> - Sabía que había que darle una serie de atenciones a la criatura en cuanto arribara a este mundo, pero no sabía cuáles (cit. en §22.2t, pág. 1570)
> - ¿No es una maravilla que los dos hayamos arribado en esta playa...? (cit. en §25.3x, pág. 1886)
> - El francés Augusto Le Moyne, quien conoció a Bogotá en 1829, y el norteamericano Strwart, quien arribó a ella en 1836, señalaron por su parte el aspecto triste y desolador que presentaba la ciudad. (cit. en §34.8q, pág. 2636)

De estos, uno no tiene complemento alguno, cuatro tiene algún complemento locativo con *a* (el que se supone es el de régimen), y uno tiene su complemento locativo con *en*.

La única cuestión que la *Nueva Gramática* se plantea frente al uso de preposiciones con *arribar* está en §29.6h (pág. 2254), pero se trata de la diferencia entre *hasta* y *a*.  No hay censura de *en*, y dudo que vayan a censurarlo, ya que en grandes obras como el *Libro de Apolonio* aparece a menudo (alterna con *a*):

> **35.** Pocos levó consigo, que no lo entendiesen,
>   fuera sus criazones otros no lo sopieron.
>   Navearon apriesa, buenos vientos hobieron,
>   arribaron en Tarso, término hí prisieron.
>
> **457.** Fueron en Mitalena los romeros arribados,
>   habían mucho mal pasado y andaban lazdrados.
>   Prisieron luego lengua, los vientos ya quedados:
>   rendían a Dios gracias porque eran escapados.

O en *Florambel de Lucea* (escrito por un Riojano, de hecho):

> Capítulo xxxiv. De cómo yendo los Cavalleros de las Flores en la estreña torre arrivaron en tierra, y de la manera que la Dueña del Fondo Valle vino a les fablar y aconsejar lo que devían fazer.

También en la [Historia de los Reyes Católicos](https://books.google.com/books?id=dFkU3Ux7KdYC&dq=%22arrivaron%20en%22&pg=PA336#v=onepage&q=%22arrivaron%20en%22&f=false):

> …cometiéronle el cargo de la conquista de Tenerife, el cual fizo su Armada de gente de Sevilla e de esta Andalucia, e de las mesmas islas de Canarias, en los Navios que huvieron menester, e arrivaron en Tenerife, e tomaron tierra e comenzaron a facer la guerra a los Gaunchos…

Y en las [Antigüedades de España](https://books.google.com/books?id=GRxPAAAAcAAJ&dq=%22arrivaron%20en%22&pg=PA576#v=onepage&q=%22arrivaron%20en%22&f=false):

> Entraron Romeros de Acre sobre mar, e arrivaron en la Isla de Chipre, e non los quiso ninguno recibir en su casa.

Cabe notar, imagino, que cuando busqué *arriva en* (porque en textos antiguos había variación con *b/v*), resulta que en francés es increíblemente común con *en*.  Si fuera influencia de otra lengua, sería galicismo.

Comment: De hecho creo que la mayoría de las lenguas europeas romances (y de las germánicas al menos el inglés y el alemán) usan verbos de movimiento del tipo de *llegar* o *arribar* con preposiciones locativas como *en* en vez de direccionales como *a*. En inglés *arrive* es préstamo del francés del s. XII. Ahora bien, ¿te das cuenta de que has mandado dos respuestas? :)

Comment: @pablodf76 sí.  Y a propósito, son dos razonamientos diferentes. Uno por el uso (más descriptivo) y otro por el análisis (más prescriptivo).  En SE no es muy común, pero se puede hacer si son respuestas suficientemente diferentes.

Comment: ¿Dos respuestas del mismo autor?

Comment: @aparente001 sí. y así la gente puede votar por la que más le guste/sastifaga